# Emotion Recognition or Feature Extraction

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a module that can recognize emotion from human faces (basic emotion such as : joy, sad, disgust, fear, surprise, neutral).

The tools I am using include :

1. OpenCV 2.4.2
2. Qt Creator
3. Mingw 4.4

First I thought I can make use of Open CV s Face Recognition module to suit my purpose and played a with it (LBPH Face recognizer), but could achieve much results. I trained the recognizer with images from different classes of emotions and do a face recognition for a sample set of image to recognize the emotion (not the person).

Then I dropped that idea and started searching for  feature extraction methods so that once I get a sample facial image I can classify it based on the extracted features (using SVM). I came across some libraries but all are meant for Visual Studio.

Is that I should change the whole project to work with visual studio?...Is there any other library which can help me to extract facial feature (with the current set of tools I am working with)...Or Am I missing somethin??

Thanks

Comment: I can't imagine a C++ library that is restricted to a particular kind of environment....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can make use of Dlib and SVM for the purpose. Get the pose of face using DLib shape prediction module and pass the the feature points(distance between upper lip,lower lip, mouth width etc) to SVM to predict the emotion. Note that the SVM predictor should be trained using sample images and their feature points